# Elasticsearch Escaping special characters in regexp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i want to search in elasticsearch using regexp but i must to escape caractere speciaux in this phrase " http://10.10.100.100/test.txt "
I tried :

```
GET indexname/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "test",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { 
              "regexp": { 
                "test.search1": "http://10.10.100.100.*" 
              }
            },
            { 
              "match": { 
                "test.search2": "url" 
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

not working.

when i replace "http://10.10.100.100.*" with "http.*"
it's working so i need to escape ":" and "//"

how to do that with elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

Elastic search has reserved few special characters. They are,

```
+ - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
```

Inorder to use those characters in the query, you need to escape them with `\`. In your case you should query with this string

```
"test.search1": "http\:\/\/10.10.100.100.*"
```

Instead of this

```
"test.search1": "http://10.10.100.100.*"
```

For more information you can refer the docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

Comment: error :  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "[10:42] [bool] failed to parse field [must]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "[10:42] [bool] failed to parse field [must]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "json_parse_exception",
      "reason" : "Unrecognized character escape ':' (code 58)\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.ByteBufferStreamInput); line: 10, column: 49]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400